# Reboot to another drive form WIndows once - after next reboot back to original drive automatically

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios, truenas

I'm looking for a way to do a reboot via TeamViewer on a remote machine from within Windows [default boot] to another drive running TrueNAS, but only for a single reboot and not permanently.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Solved by EasyUEFI, even allows one time boot with one click